# JSch/SSHJ - Connecting to SSH server on button click

Tags: button, ssh, click, jsch

I'm trying to connect to SSH Unix server on button click (code written in actionPerformed() method). I'm using JSch for connecting to SSH server. The code is written in SwingWorker class as it is a network operation.

```
private void testConnectionButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     

        SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> sw = new SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>(){

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
                JSch jsch = new JSch();

                String host = "ServerHost";
                String username = "username";
                String password = "password";

                Session session = jsch.getSession(username, host);
                session.setPassword(password);

                session.setTimeout(20000);
                System.out.println("Connecting to server...");
                session.connect();

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void done(){
                try {
                    System.out.println(get().toString());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.err(ex);
                } 
            }
        };

        sw.execute();

    }
```

But after running the with correct host, username and password details, I get the below error all the time:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: timeout: socket is not established
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.get(SwingWorker.java:583)
```

But whenever I run the same code in standalone program, I mean instead for writing actionPerformed() method, If I write it in normal method and calling from main() method. It will work. when I integrate the same code with Button Click's actionPerformed() method, it will give me above exception.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong here or any modification should be made to the code.

I tried to connect to SSH Server using "SSHJ" implementation, but I get the below error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.get(SwingWorker.java:583)
```

Can someone help me - how to move forward?

Comment: It works for me (if I change the server names, password, and the settings to accept the server's public key, and correct your `system.out.err`).

Comment: Paulo, can you tell what are the settings you want me to put to accept server's public key, a piece of code will be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: [`JSch.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")`](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html#config-others). But this is not your problem, your program does not even get to this point (the connection is refused or not allowed). Check your firewall settings.

Comment: I did the same thing after you have asked me to put the code to accept the server's public key, but it didn't connect to server, firewall settings are fine because when I ran it standalone without putting the code in actionPerformed() method - it will work, but when I connect this code with actionPerformed() method - it won't connect. Not able to find out the correct reason for this. Any further suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your code, wrapped it in some GUI code (and converted it to non-generics to be able to compile it with the same settings as the rest of the JSch examples). It works for me. Try this, and report what exception you get (it has a bit more exception logging).

```java
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import com.jcraft.jsch.*;



class SwingWorkerExample {

    JTextField hostField;
    JTextField userNameField;
    JTextField passwordField;
    JPanel panel;


    public SwingWorkerExample() {
        JPanel p = panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2));
        hostField = new JTextField(20);
        userNameField = new JTextField(20);
        passwordField = new JPasswordField(20);
        JButton testButton = new JButton("connect!");
        testButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                    testConnectionButtonActionPerformed(ev);
                }
            });
        p.add(new JLabel("host:"));
        p.add(hostField);
        p.add(new JLabel("user:"));
        p.add(userNameField);
        p.add(new JLabel("password:"));
        p.add(passwordField);
        p.add(testButton);
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }

    private void testConnectionButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        SwingWorker sw = new SwingWorker(){

                protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    try {
                        JSch jsch = new JSch();

                        String host = hostField.getText();
                        String username = userNameField.getText();
                        String password = passwordField.getText();

                        Session session = jsch.getSession(username, host);
                        session.setPassword(password);
                        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

                        session.setTimeout(20000);
                        System.out.println("Connecting to server...");
                        session.connect();

                        return session;
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }

                public void done(){
                    try {
                        System.out.println(get());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

        sw.execute();

    }


    public static void main(String[] egal) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run() {
            SwingWorkerExample ex = new SwingWorkerExample();
            JFrame f = new JFrame("bla");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setContentPane(ex.getPanel());
            f.pack();
            f.setVisible(true);
        }});
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also available at github in my [JSch-documentation repository](https://github.com/ePaul/jsch-documentation/blob/swingworker-example/examples/SwingWorkerExample.java) (branch swingworker-example, for now).

Comment: Paulo, I have executed your code, it is working fine. I am creating GUI using Netbeans 7, there is one class: [org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap] using which I'm getting the property values from Properties file. I'm using it for setting text for button, label texts. If I don't use this class file in the code, the session.connect() is working. I really don't know the relation here why it is failing to connect. If I use even one line of ResourceMap class, it will not connecting. Any thoughts on it?

Comment: No idea, I never used this class. This could be a classloader problem - maybe some class is duplicated in your classpath, leading to loading of the wrong one if ResourceMap is used, due to some dependencies?

Comment: this class is not present in my class path, I tried with "javap org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap". It is strange to observe this kind of behavior, so only way is to avoid this class for now?