# JSchException timeout: socket is not established

Tags: java, sockets, ssh, jsch

I am trying to use [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/) to connect to my computer through ssh and then run a command.

However, when I run the code I never connect to the computer. and the following error:

`I/System.out: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: timeout: socket is not established`

Here is my relevant code:

```
protected void sshTesting(){
    String name = "";
    String userName = "kalenpw";
    String password = "hunter2";
    String ip = "192.168.0.4";
    int port = 22;
    String command = "cmus-remote -u";

    try{
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(userName, ip, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");


        System.out.println("Establishing connection");
        session.connect(10);

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        channel.connect(10000);

//            name = session.getUserName();
//            System.out.println(session.getHost());


    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.print(e);
        System.out.print(e);
    }        

}
```

This is my first time using JSch so I am pretty much just following one of their examples [Exec.java](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html). I have found this answer [JSch/SSHJ - Connecting to SSH server on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819246/jsch-sshj-connecting-to-ssh-server-on-button-click) which unfortunately my code looks like it is establishing a connection in a similar fashion yet with no results. I have tested SSHing into my computer normally and it works fine so I don't believe the issue is with the server, but with my code.

Here is the entire stack trace:

```
W/System.err: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: timeout: socket is not establishedcom.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: timeout: socket is not established
W/System.err:     at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:394)
W/System.err:     at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)
W/System.err:     at com.example.kalenpw.myfirstapp.RectangleClickActivity.sshTesting(RectangleClickActivity.java:97)
W/System.err:     at com.example.kalenpw.myfirstapp.RectangleClickActivity$1.onCheckedChanged(RectangleClickActivity.java:56)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:165)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.Switch.setChecked(Switch.java:1151)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.Switch.toggle(Switch.java:1146)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:123)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22589)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

`RectangleClickActivity.java` is the file I am testing SSH.

line 97 is: `session.connect(10);`

line 56 is: `sshTesting();`

Comment: Have you looked at the traffic using Wireshark to see if it's even attempting a connection?  Nobody here can possibly help without more information other than suggest that there's a network or firewall issue between your two systems.

Comment: @JimGarrison yes, I can connect though a terminal. I just tried Wireshark, never used it before so I'm not sure how to analyze it in detail but when I try to connect there are several entries with my computer as their destination so I believe it is trying to connect. I'm not sure a network or firewall is the issue since I am on the same local network, but perhaps there is. What else can I check to determine that?

Comment: Which line in your code throws the exception? Also post the complete stack trace.

Comment: @JimGarrison it is the line I call `session.connect(10)` I just edited all of that into my question

Comment: I _strongly_ suggest you examine the code for [com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.53/com/jcraft/jsch/Util.java#Util.createSocket%28java.lang.String%2Cint%2Cint%29) which looks pretty shaky to me. To implement a timeout it does the connect in a thread and if the thread doesn't end by the timeout it declares the connection failed.  I'd add the source to your IDE and trace into this in your debugger to see what's really happening.  It could be a bug in JSch.  Welcome to the world of Open Source.... :-)

Comment: I am having same code except that I am adding authorizedkeyfile to Jsch Connection , and still getting "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: timeout: socket is not established". Here is the extra code ```File keyFile = new File(SshConnectionTest.class.getResource(privateKey).toURI()); 
          String privateKeyAbsolutePath = keyFile.getAbsolutePath();
          jsch.addIdentity(privateKeyAbsolutePath);```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue ended up being I was setting the config to `session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");`, but for some reason you need to create a config and set the StrictHostKeyChecking and then add that config to the session instead of just setting it directly.

The working code looks like this:

```
protected void sshTesting(){
    String name = "";
    String userName = "kalenpw";
    String password = "hunter2";
    String ip = "192.168.0.4";
    int port = 22;
    String command = "cmus-remote -u";

    try{
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(userName, ip, port);
        session.setPassword(password);

        //Missing code
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        //


        System.out.println("Establishing connection");
        session.connect(10);

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        channel.connect(10000);

//            name = session.getUserName();
//            System.out.println(session.getHost());

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.print(e);
        System.out.print(e);
    }        

}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those that encounter this same exception:

> "JSchException timeout: socket is not established"

you might need to increase the timeout value in jsch's session properties prior to attempt the connection.

Make sure that a large enough value is set to allow the connection to succeed.

For example:

```
...
session.setTimeout(15000);
session.connect();
...
```

will set a 15sec timeout on your connection, that should be enough time to establish the socket.
In your code above, even though is not well documented, this call is setting 10 millisecs for your connection:
    ...
        session.connect(10); 
    ...
which is very low. Remove the 10 and leave it as:
    ...
        session.connect(); 
    ...
Setting the StrictHostKeyChecking property might have solved the problem reducing the time it took the socket to connect but it might not be the right solution as the timeout you have is too small and it will likely fail sporadically.